# best query to update a big mysql database (rows) against a badword list

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with 8 million rows, which needs to be scanned against a huge list of badwords.

My first idea was to:

```
UPDATE `master` SET `blacklisted`='1' WHERE MATCH (`content-desc`, `content-title`) AGAINST ('
badword1 | badword2 | badword3 | "and many more"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

unfortunately this version forgot some words and was not case-insensitive!

next try was to

```
$badwords = array("badword1","badword2","badword3","and-many-more");

foreach($badwords AS $name)
   {
        $sql = "UPDATE `master` SET `blacklisted`='1' WHERE concat(`content-title(mediumtext)`,`content-desc(mediumtext)`)  LIKE '%".$name."%'";

        sleep(6);

// Could limit this query by 100.000 and adding another foreach loop help?
// How would the foreach look like (select count(*) from master?)/100.000

   }
```

a lot of queries which killed my server immediately!
Maybe the commented idea could help?! (but howto?)

Who has the best idea how to solve this query, without stressing the mysql server too much?
Thank you!

Comment: The first one should have been case insensitive. What collation are you using? Also, don't use `|` for `or`. `Or` is [implied](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), just use space.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this will perform on your table, but you can do a case insensitive comparison, as part of a join clause.

**So, you have a table that you want to scan (with 8m rows)**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `haystack` (
  `word` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table `haystack`

INSERT INTO `haystack` (`word`) VALUES
('a cat is'),
('category'),
('cat'),
('decatur'),
('dog'),
('pigeon'),
('eagle'),
('a beagle'),
('Cat'),
('CAT');

**And a table with bad words**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `needles` (
  `bad_word` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table `needles`

INSERT INTO `needles` (`bad_word`) VALUES
('cat'),
('eagle');

**The following query will JOIN the two tables, case-insensitively, with fuzzy matching.**

SELECT * FROM haystack AS h JOIN needles AS n ON h.word COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE CONCAT('%' , n.bad_word , '%');

You can of course, perform an update on the results easily enough.  Here are the results I got...  If you do not want to exclude words like "Dickson", "Stitsville", "Assume", it gets much more tricky.

**word         bad_word**

a cat is     cat

category     cat

cat          cat

decatur      cat

eagle        eagle

a beagle     eagle

Cat          cat

CAT          cat

Comment: The trick to making it case insensitive, in the comparison that drives the join, is the specification of the COLLATION (COLLATE utf8_general_ci) which is a case insensitive version of the UTF8 general collation.  There are similar collations for latin character sets if that is what you're using.